# Get genomic coordinates using GenomicFeatures by HGNC gene names

Tags: r, bioconductor, sequence-annotation

I want to get coordinates of human genes from my list (consisting of hgnc genes id) using GenomicFeatures and TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene R packages from Bioconductor.

```
library(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene)
txdb=(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene)

my_genes = c("INO80","NASP","INO80D","SMARCA1")

select(txdb, keys = my_genes,
   columns=c("TXCHROM","TXSTART","TXEND","TXSTRAND"), 
   keytype="GENEID")
```

However, it doesn't' work because txdb doesn't take hgnc identifiers; how can it be solved? I couldn't find any appropriate keytype that will support hgnc and not sure how to match hgnc id I have and GENEID from txdb.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from @devon-ryan, converted from comment:*

Try a UCSC gene ID instead. For those genes they'd be: `uc001zni.3` (INO80), `uc002vaz.4` (INO80D), `uc004eup.4` or `uc004eun.4` (SMARCA1) and `uc001coj.2`, `uc010olq.2`, `uc010olr.2`, `uc001coi.2` or `uc001col.2` (NASP). You might have to omit the versions (the `.4` part, for example).